# Substitute only part of regex in re.sub

Tags: python, regex, substitution

I'd like to only substitute parts of the regex passed into `re.sub` (the `[^\d+]` is just to make sure that no digit is coming after this, i.e. that the whole integer (with all digits) is captured). However, the code belows substitutes the next character (i.e. in the first example swallowing the next " ").

```
import re
pattern = r'foo-%d[^\d+]'

k = 12 # only substitute entire "foo-12" occurrences
result = re.sub(pattern % k, '@foo-%d@' % k, 'dasds foo-12 gfd9843')
# got: result == 'dasds @foo-12@gfd9843'
assert result == 'dasds @foo-12@ gfd9843', result

k = 1 # only substitute entire "foo-1" occurrences
result = re.sub(pattern % k, '@foo-%d@' % k, 'dasds foo-12 gfd9843')
assert result == 'dasds foo-12 gfd9843', result

k = 1 # only substitute entire "foo-1" occurrences
result = re.sub(pattern % k, '@foo-%d@' % k, 'dasds foo-11 gfd9843')
assert result == 'dasds foo-11 gfd9843', result
```

How can I fix this? Am I at least on the right track with the regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\b` here

```
import re
k = 12 # only substitute entire "foo-12" occurrences
s = 'dasds foo-12 gfd9843'
result = re.sub(r'foo-%d\b' % k, '@foo-%d@' % k, s)

# got: result == 'dasds @foo-12@gfd9843'
assert result == 'dasds @foo-12@ gfd9843', result


k = 1 # only substitute entire "foo-1" occurrences
result = re.sub(r'foo-%d\b' % k, '@foo-%d@' % k, s)
assert result == 'dasds foo-12 gfd9843', result
```

Comment: Not sure what `\b` does, but the `+` doesn't work. See my added test case.

Comment: @orange sry `+` was not needed...try now